# perl object constructor

Tags: perl, constructor

I read in a tutorial, something like that to call the constructor:

```
my $v = Vehicule->new( 2, "bleu" );
```

Then the concerned class is something like that

```
sub new {
    my ($class,$nbRoues,$couleur) = @_;
    my $this = {};
    bless($this, $class);
    $this->{NB_ROUES} = $nbRoues;
    $this->{COULEUR} = $couleur;
    return $this;
}
```

The thing I don't understand is how/why `@_` first element contains the classname?

```
my ($class,$nbRoues,$couleur) = @_
```

when we call it like this `Vehicule->new( 2, "bleu" );`

Same for method/function of the class with something like that

```
my ($this) = @_ ;
```

Actually I don't really understand `Class->new` or `$var->method`

Comment: Because, perl evaluates `Vehicule->new(2, "bleu")` as `new Vehicule 2 "bleu"` akin to other perl subroutine calls. IOW, `new` is just a sub. Have a look at [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#A-Method-is-Simply-a-Subroutine)

Answer (score 3):

The short, but admittedly unsatisfying, answer to your question is simply "because that's the way it works".

Perl was not an OO language initially, so the OO support was kind of taped to the side of existing things in a way that allows it to make use of as much of what was previously there as possible.  Part of that implementation is that when a `sub` is called as a method, the class or object that it was called on is added to the beginning of its argument list.  `MyClass->new(@args)` is roughly equivalent to `MyClass::new('MyClass', @args)` and, if `$obj` is an instance of `MyClass`, `$obj->foo(@args)` is roughly equivalent to `MyClass::foo($obj, @args)`.

The reason that I say they're "roughly equivalent" rather than "identical" is that the method call version (using `->`) will search `@ISA` for inherited implementations if the method isn't implemented by `MyClass`, while the `sub` call version will not.